# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object in pandasql

Tags: python

I'm running pandasql in my python 3.x. I have a customer - city data. Sample of which is given below:

I want to retrieve distinct Customer_number by city. So I used following code

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import os 
import pandasql as pdsql
os.chdir(path) 

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""CUSTOMER_ID, City
21397845, Birmingham
26396841, Anchorage
52396841, Bullhead
67896841, Flagstaff"""))

def Cust(city_value):


    city='"'+city_value+'"'
    print("city="+city)

    str2='select * from df_city where City='+ city
    pysql = lambda q: pdsql.sqldf(q, globals())
    df1 = pysql(str2)
    return df1
```

df_city is a global variable.But after running this query I'm getting following error message

```
 File "<ipython-input-53-5bbe2c883433>", line 17, in Cust
    df1 = pysql(str2)

  File "<ipython-input-53-5bbe2c883433>", line 15, in <lambda>
    pysql = lambda q: pdsql.sqldf(q, globals())

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py", line 156, in sqldf
    return PandaSQL(db_uri)(query, env)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py", line 50, in __call__
    for table_name in extract_table_names(query):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py", line 108, in extract_table_names
    tables_blocks = re.findall(r'(?:FROM|JOIN)\s+(\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*)', query, re.IGNORECASE)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
```

Can you please help me to modify my code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post data or code as image. See also [here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). I proposed an edit to your code to change that. Please review/accept if it is correct.

Comment: sry.. typo.... please replace `StringIO` by `io.StringIO`

Comment: Sure @akraf.Next Time I will do that. Are you saying me to import io.StringIO instead of your import io command? Import io.StringIO is not working in my python.I think I have to do `conda install io.StringIO` before importing

Comment: Instead of `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(` write `df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(`. No need to install anything AFAIK, as the `io` packages is included per default in python

Comment: Unfortunately I currently have no pandasql on my machine and can not try it.. but might it have something to do with your global variable being called `df` and in `str2` there is `... FROM df_city...`?

Comment: I did that but still getting error message TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Kindly install pandasql & suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not reproduce your Problem, this works for me (Python 2.7.5)

```
import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as pdsql 

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""CUSTOMER_ID,City
21397845,Birmingham
26396841,Anchorage
52396841,Bullhead
67896841,Flagstaff"""))

def Cust(city_value):
    city='"'+city_value+'"'
    print("city="+city)
    str2='select * from df where City='+ city
    pysql = lambda q: pdsql.sqldf(q, globals())
    df1 = pysql(str2)
    return df1

Cust('Birmingham')
```

Returns:

```
   CUSTOMER_ID        City
0     21397845  Birmingham
```

[*Note*: I removed the white spaces in the `df` data compared to your post (my edit, sry another time... :-/)

Comment: I'm using python 3.6. Is there any change in 3.X version?

Comment: I found this string format is working for me `str2="""select * from df where City='Birmingham'""" ` Can you please suggest me how do I add city variable instead of Birmingham here?

Comment: I found way I used  str1="""select * from df where City='%s'"""   str2=str1%city

Comment: Though I do not understand why this works, and your original solution did not, great that it works!